# PHP variable inside of HTML string value - Why won't it work?

Tags: php

Basically I'm a little confused to why this won't work, no errors or anything, it's just simply blank, it has worked before, but it's now deciding not to work it's just really strange.

This is what i'm trying to do: ($id does have a value and it's currently being echoed out on the page with no issue)

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php $id ?>"/>
```

Comment: Never mind, it was a server error it's now working sorry about this and thank you i'll accept your question.

Comment: *"Never mind, it was a server error it's now working sorry"* you edited your question entirely and accepted an answer that wasn't the reason for this whole mess. You're sending out the wrong message here. I've rolled it back to your original post with a formatting fix.

Comment: You need to `echo` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are missing ECHO command between `<?PHP  ?>` tags

and in your HTML Code you are define `<?PHP $id ?>` but in your PHP code you don't have an ID you have

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
```

Comment: I have tried this. It does not work.

Comment: can you add your complete code to your question

Answer (score 2):

`$id` stores some value

`echo $id` outputs the value of `$id`.

`<?= $id ?>` is short for `<?php echo $id ?>`

Comment: I have tried this. It does not work.

Comment: I do not know your code, so I cannot tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: what does the rendered html look like ?